# Difference between content of stream and the string `str()` returns?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I'm using [a small piece of code](http://www.vulcanware.com/cpp_pdf/index.html) that generates PDF files, which I found on the internet, and tried to (softly) optimize it as the creation of a file would take ages. After profiling, I narrowed it down to the following piece of code :

```
std::ostringstream tmp;
tmp << std::hex << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') <<
    std::setw(2) << r << " " <<
    std::setw(2) << g << " " <<
    std::setw(2) << b;

out << tmp.str();
```

found in a tight loop, with `out` being a `ostringstream` that contains basically the whole PDF content before it's written into the file. I found that `tmp.str()` was the line that took the most time in that loop, and saw when looking up the C++ reference that `str()` would return a copy of the stream's underlying string.

Then, I thought removing that copy and using directly `out` would be faster. So I dumped `tmp` and directly did:

```
out << std::hex << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') <<
    std::setw(2) << r << " " <<
    std::setw(2) << g << " " <<
    std::setw(2) << b;
```

But now, the PDF file generated is considered "broken" and can't be opened by a PDF reader, while the previous one could be. I created a PDF with both methods (with the `tmp` stream and without) to compare the lines output, but found no obvious differences...

Then, what could be the reason for this ? Is there a reason to use that temporary stream ? Is it, and why could it be different than directly using the `out` stream ?

I thought it could be something related either to newlines or to the manipulators, but couldn't find anything significant on these

Comment: Did you find any non-obvious differences, then? Presumably, *any* difference could account for the broken behavior. Are the files identical? Your diff tool should be able to identify differences for you.

Comment: @RobKennedy Yes, I tried to diff the files, but couldn't manage to do it unfortunately (Notepad++ "Compare" made it crash, `fc` in Windows also crashed or gave something strange like "cant re-synchronize files" in the middle of the diff). That's why I tried to print both lines in the same files to compare.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing to consider is that the io manipulators (for example `std::hex`) are persistent from that point forward on the stream.

So once you insert the `std::hex` manipulator, all integral values are printed out in hex format from this point forward.

Your previous approach did not have this problem as the manipulator was on a transient stream. You could try inserting the `std::dec` manipulator once you are done...

Pulling up from Jan Hudec's comment, [Boost IO State Savers](http://www.boost.org/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html) are the nice way forward to handle this cleanly.

Comment: Yup, it worked, good point. I did not know that these manipulators were persistent.

Comment: Even better option is to use [Boost IO State Savers](http://www.boost.org/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html). They are header-only and you should be able to take them out of boost if you don't want to use all of it.

Comment: To underscore the comment from @JanHudec: in general you should leave a stream in the same state as you found it. Using `std::dec` to undo `std::hex` is only correct if the stream's state was decimal when it came in. Instead of hard-coding that, use something smarter to save the original state on entry and restore it on exit.

Comment: @JanHudec, that's quite neat!

Comment: Another alternative is to save the state in your manipulators, and restore it in their destructor.  You don't want to use the standard manipulators anyway; in a case like this, you would want a `color` or `colorElement` manipulator.

Comment: And the Boost IO State Savers don't look very well designed.  Basically, you want to save the format, precision and fill, and nothing else (especially not iostate).  Boost doesn't seem to give you this option.

Comment: @JamesKanze,hmm, looking more at it, it seems that there are several state savers that are provided including format, precision and fill, and I think the way it's designed, it's up to you which savers you instantiate for the given stream. In this way, it's quite flexible...

Comment: @Nim Overly flexible, but with no simple single instance for what must surely be the most common, if not the only use.  Basically, the author just provides savers for everything the class offers, with no attempt to consider whether they make sense or not, and no attempt to consider usability.

Answer (score 2):

Another little difference: If the formatted output to the std::ostringstream fails the destination out is not affected.

(Nim's answer describes the actual problem)